# AngularJS: Accessing an unnamed property

Tags: angularjs

I console.logged a variable called $scope.loan.farms and the console shows 4 objects inside of this variable (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAjfy.jpg). In angular.forEach how would I access the irr property for each? I don't know how to access it since the inner objects are unnamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`farms` is probally an array, so something like this:

```
var arr = $scope.loan.farms;
for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
{
   var curr = arr[i]; // curr is your object..
   console.log(curr.county.id);
}
```

Comment: awesome answer, thanks! The irr property is a string of 1 and I need to turn it into a boolean. How would I go about returning the boolean to $scope.loan.farms?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to change irr = "0" to irr = false and irr = "1" to irr = true?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I need to do on the $scope variable

Comment: I dont know how your model is built and binded so I would create a new property `curr.irrBoolean = curr.irr == "0" ? false : true;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
angular.foreach($scope loan.farms, function(farm) {
    farm.irr = farm.irr=="1";
});
```